# Iterating Through Firebase Array

Tags: arrays, json, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

When I get a snapshot of the database I see this:

```
{
    "9-17-2017" =     {
        "19:26:38" =         {
            1abA = 1ab;
            1abrA = 1;
            2abA = 2ab;
            2abrA = 2;
            3abA = 3ab;
            4abA = 4ab;
            5abA = 5a;
            6abA = 6ab;
            7abA = 7ab;
            Date = "9-17-2017";
            Time = "19:26:38";
            anA = an;
            apnA = apn;
            q1A = 1;
            q2A = 2;
            q3A = 3;
            q4A = 4;
            q5A = 5;
            q6A = 6;
        };
        "20:16:15" =         {
            1abA = 1qwe;
            1abrA = 3;
            2abA = "D.C.";
            2abrA = 7;
            3abA = wedded;
            4abA = wedge;
            5abA = qdwfeg;
            6abA = qwfegr;
            7abA = wedge;
            Date = "9-17-2017";
            Time = "20:16:15";
            anA = "we're";
            apnA = apn;
            q1A = 7;
            q2A = 2;
            q3A = 7;
            q4A = 4;
            q5A = 5;
            q6A = 7;
        };
    };
}
```

I want to be able to set a label to the value of the key 1abA but I can't seem to figure out a way to sort through the array.

I am using this code to get the snapshot:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!) ref.child("PostGameEval").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.value!)
        })
```

Comment: what do you mean by "set a label to the value of the key 1abA "

Comment: @Siyavash so I want to be able to set the value of key 1abA  which is "1ab" to a uilabel so how can I single out each key and get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given it a try hope this helps you:

I have taken the data as shown in figure above as follows:

Here `dict` is equivalent to `snapshot.value` above:

```
    let dict = [
        "9-17-2017" :    [
                "19:26:38" :        [
                        "1abA" : "1ab",
                        "1abrA" : 1
                ],
                "20:16:15" :         [
                        "1abA" : "1qwe",
                        "1abrA" : 3

                ],
                "19:23:38" :        [
                        "1abA" : "1ab",
                        "1abrA" : 1
                ],
                "21:16:15" :         [
                        "1abA" : "1qwe",
                        "1abrA" : 3

                ]

        ],
        "9-16-2017":   [
                "19:20:38" :        [
                        "1abA" : "1ax",
                        "1abrA" : 4
                ],
                "20:01:15" :         [
                        "1abA" : "1qe",
                        "1abrA" : 0

                ],
                "19:23:38" :        [
                        "1abA" : "1ab",
                        "1abrA" : 1
                ],
                "21:16:15" :         [
                        "1abA" : "1qwe",
                        "1abrA" : 3

                ]

        ]

]
```

Note: I think in your case you can get `dict` as follows:

```
if let dict = snaphot.value as? [String : [String: [String: Any]] {
    //then use the following code here
}
```

Now getting the values for key `1abA` I used this code:

```
let keys = Array(dict.keys)

var myLabel = ""
for i in 0..<keys.count {
        if let innerDict = dict[keys[i]] {
                let innerKeys = Array((innerDict).keys)
                let sortedInnerKeys = innerKeys.sorted(by: { $0 > $1} )
                for j in 0..<2 {
                        if let tempDict = innerDict[sortedInnerKeys[j]] {
                                //myLabel = tempDict["1abA"] as! String
                                print("Value of Key 1abA for innerKey \(sortedInnerKeys[j]) is \(tempDict["1abA"] ?? "")")
                                print("Value of Key 1abrA for innerKey \(sortedInnerKeys[j]) is \(tempDict["1abrA"] ?? "")")
                        }
                }
        }

}
```

Output:

> Value of Key 1abA for innerKey 21:16:15 is 1qwe
>
> Value of Key 1abrA for innerKey 21:16:15 is 3
>
> Value of Key 1abA for innerKey 20:01:15 is 1qe
>
> Value of Key 1abrA for innerKey 20:01:15 is 0
>
> Value of Key 1abA for innerKey 21:16:15 is 1qwe
>
> Value of Key 1abrA for innerKey 21:16:15 is 3
>
> Value of Key 1abA for innerKey 20:16:15 is 1qwe
>
> Value of Key 1abrA for innerKey 20:16:15 is 3

Comment: So how can I loop that to get all the key values of my original json

Comment: @WillMays sorry I couldnt understand , please explain with example, what do you mean

Comment: If I want to do the same for q1A and q2a do I use the same code just add tempDict["q1A"] and so on for every value?

Comment: @WillMays yes I believe so, you can get value for any key in that dictionary

Comment: What about if I only want the last 7 based on the time?

Comment: @WillMays yes you can do that by first sorting the innerKeys in descending order and then get the value for first seven key values

Comment: Could you add that to the answer to do that? Thanks

Comment: @WillMays I have updated the answer, it now gets the values for the 2 times that are the latest of all times and also you can see the value for key `1abrA ` as well

Comment: use of unresolved identifier "keys" in "for i in 0..<keys.count {"

Comment: @WillMays sorry my bad, I edited the code and removed that line , please see the updated the code

Comment: yes this works but if I search for last 3 values and I only have 2 it crashes

Comment: @WillMays Good, yes that will crash so you have to check the count before accessing the values

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @WillMays you can use this `if (sortedInnerKeys.count < whatevervalueyouwant)`  and then execute the code inside it, something like that, I would suggest go through this :https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID127

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154719/discussion-between-will-mays-and-3stud1ant3).